# React functional components with methods

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If we wanted to make a functional stateless component but we want methods that are able to access the props how would we do that? Is there like a general rule or best practice when it comes to things like this

for example

```
function Stateless(props) {
   function doSomething(props) {
      console.log(props);
   }
  doSomething() // logs 'undefined'
return (
  <div> some stuff </div>
}
```

the inside props is always not the props that given, at least in my experience.

If I didn't need a state (using Redux) but still wanted methods that accessed props, is it still good practice to use classes and not stateless functions?

Comment: Why just call doSomething() without parameter? It seems that you have to change doSomething() to doSomething(props) to make sense

Comment: `doSomething(/*props you are passing is undefined*/)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is perfectly fine to use functions inside functional components. In fact [React hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) that were introduced recently in React 16.8, are all about making functional components even more convenient by bringing state and lifecycle events to the the functional components via [special hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

But as others have mentioned you need to pass proper arguments to your functions: `doSomething(props)` or not pass arguments at all and correspondingly never expect them in function declaration itself: `function doSomething()`.

Answer (score 3):

doSomething() logs undefined because the inner props variable wasn't delivered when you called doSomething(missing props).
You can either remove the inner props:

```
function Stateless(props) {
  function doSomething() {
    console.log(props);
  }
  doSomething();
  return (
    <div> some stuff </div>
  );
}
```

Or declare doSomething outside your component:

```
function doSomething(props) {
  console.log(props);
}
function Stateless(props) {
  doSomething(props);
  return (
    <div> some stuff </div>
  );
}
```

Both will work. The first might be easier, but if your component is redrawn often, the second is more performant, since you only declare doSomething once.

Answer (score 2):

```
function Stateless(props) {
   function doSomething() { // 1. props is accessible inside the function so you can skip the parameter
      console.log(props);
   }
  doSomething();
return (
  <div> some stuff </div>
)//2. missing paranthesis
}
```